# my codes are not working in visual studios

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, methods

i have an error that says that i do not have a method called 'GetUser' even though it is there.. The error says: 
"System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal' does not contain a definition for 'GetUser' and no extension method 'GetUser' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal' could be found "

This is my code in User class

```
public static List<User> GetUser()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = null;
        List<User> result = new List<User>();
        try
        {
            conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["2ndEardbConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
            comm.Connection = conn;
            comm.CommandText = "select * from User";
            SqlDataReader dr = comm.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                User u = new User();
                u.Name = (string)dr["Name"];
                u.UserName = (string)dr["UserName"];
                u.Password = (string)dr["Password"];
                u.DOB = (DateTime)dr["DOB"];
                u.Gender = (string)dr["Gender"];
                u.Email = (string)dr["Email"];
                u.ContactNumber = (int)dr["ContactNumber"];
                u.ProfilePic = (byte)dr["ProfilePic"];
                u.Image = (byte)dr["Image"];


                result.Add(u);
            }
            dr.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

and in the form, this is the code i had put

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<User> results = User.GetUser();
        foreach (User u in results)
        {
            if (TextBox8.Text.ToString() == u.UserName.ToString())
            {
                Label13.Visible = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                Label12.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

However the error occurs at User.GetUser():

Stating that there is no method.

How do i go about solving this in visual studios C#
 Please help
Thank you

Comment: where did you put the user class? are you missing a using directive ?

Comment: The `GetUser` function looks correct. Are you sure its actually in the `User` class? The compiler seems to disagree. Could you post the code for the `User` class?

Comment: Please change the title of this question

Comment: You mispelled the title, it should be: "my *codez* are not working"

Comment: It seems like your 'User' class is located in the different namespace. And is this class defined like 'public'?

Comment: Both the namespace for the class and form are the same.

Answer (score 4):

You are not calling your GetUser method, but the System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal one. Use full namespace.

```
List<User> results = MyNamespace.User.GetUser();
```